# data binding from panorama item

Tags: c#, json, xaml, binding

Here is my situation...

I have one Panorama which obtain JSON data from a web service.
It contain News, which include image, Title, content, post date, and type of news.
Now I can generate that Panorama to display the pictures, Title, and content of each one, with these code of XAML below.

```
<controls:Panorama x:Name="NewsPanorama" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Title="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="750" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="477" Margin="-2,0,0,0">
            <controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:PanoramaItem Orientation="Horizontal" Header="{Binding Type}">
                        <Grid Height="595" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-21,0,0">
                            <Image x:Name="imgAds1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="595" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="417" Source="{Binding Image.Url}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="106" Margin="0,489,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="417" Opacity="0.44"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Title" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="81" Margin="7,489,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="397" FontSize="40"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Content" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="7,540,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="397" FontSize="15"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="TypeOfContent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="7,590,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Type}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="397" FontSize="15" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </controls:PanoramaItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Panorama.ItemTemplate>
            <controls:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Panorama.HeaderTemplate>
        </controls:Panorama>
```

But when I want to navigate with Tab method on my Panorama. I don't know how to get the properties, which are title or type of news to the navigated page.
For example, I want to get TypeOfContent TextBlock or {Binding Type} for my navigation, but I don't know how to do.

Now my navigation code in c# is like this.

```
void NewsPanorama_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedIndex = NewsPanorama.SelectedIndex;
        //I just try something that doesn't work here.
        /*Panorama panoramactrl = (Panorama)sender;
        PanoramaItem panoramaItem = (PanoramaItem)(panoramactrl.SelectedItem);*/
        //String header = NewsPanorama.SelectedItem.Header.ToString();


        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ViewContentDetail.xaml?itemId=" + selectedIndex , UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

You can see that I can send the selectedIndex to ViewContentDetail.xaml but I can't send the header of the NewsPanorama.SelectedItem to that page. Because I need some properties from PanoramaItem to retrieve another JSON from web service.

Can you give me some suggestion of what to do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the selected index, you can get the item directly from the Items collection which you used for binding:

```
var selectedItem = Items[NewsPanorama.SelectedIndex];
```

Other way is to get the DataContext of the selected item and cast it, something like this:

```
var selectedItem = (NewsPanorama.SelectedItem as PanoramaItem).DataContext as SomeItem;
```

Comment: After I did something like this, there is still NullException.    PanoramaItem selectedItem = NewsPanorama.Items[selectedIndex] as PanoramaItem;
            String header = selectedItem.Header.ToString();

Comment: that's because you mixed up my two ideas into one.